# Flutter - "Invalid constant value" inside OnChange - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to do a very basic Log in app in Flutter. I'm trying to get the email and password from a TextField Widget with OnChange, but it gives me this error "Invalid constant value", inside of the function of OnChange. What can I do?. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String email = '';
String password = '';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Text(
                'Welcome to the log in'
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'email',
                ),
                onChanged: (text) {
                  email = text; //Error here
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'password',
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The I tried to elimanate the const label from Column, but gives me the warning "Prefer const with constant constructors".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `const` needs to be removed:

```
children: const <Widget>[
```

Then you can add `const` in other places. I'd guess that the IDE helps you out there. It could be used e.g. here `padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),` so the result will be:

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
```

and so forth...

Comment: Thank you so much!, I ended up putting const in EdgeInsets and in InputDecoration, but this bring me another question, is there a way of doing it without using so many "const"? Or is this the recommend way to solve this warnings?

Comment: There is no other way. What you are doing is telling the compiler that this object is constant and that will in turn make sure to only create one such object, that is then re-used in the entire app when the exact same parameters etc is set. When your IDE tells you "Prefer const..." it is not a warning, it is an info-message. It is hinting you how to optimze your code.  I don't know what IDE you are using, but in vscode you can get the quick-fix option "Add const modifiers everywhere in file", which just fixes it for you everywhere...